# Blackberry CheckboxField[] - FieldChangeListener - Stackoverflow error

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, checkbox

I have an array of CheckboxField[] elements that I need to dynamically initialize. My sample code is -

```
class abc extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {
    CheckboxField[] boxField;
    abc() {
        .
        .
        .
        boxField = new CheckboxField[length];
        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            boxField[i] = new CheckboxField(var[i], false);
            boxField[i].setChangeListener(this);
            vfm.add(boxField[i]);
        }
        add(vfm);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        // The idea is to disable all the other checkboxes when one
        // is clicked. 
        boxField[0].setChecked(false); // Gives stackoverflow error on JVM.
    }
}
```

Any help?

Edit: The problem only seems to be with .setChecked(boolean)
I've tried chkboxField[0].setFont(), chkboxField.getChecked(), both of them seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what's apparently happening is `boxField[i].setChecked(false)` calls the FieldChangeListener again, and this loops infinitely till the stack blows.

I was told to use

```
if(context != FieldChangeListener.PROGRAMMATIC) {
   boxField[i].setChecked(false); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment in the FieldChanged method, it sounds like you have mutually exclusive checkboxes (that is, you have a group of checkboxes and when any one is checked, all the rest should be unchecked).

If so, you may want to consider using the **RadioButtonField** instead. You can stick your radio buttons into a **RadioButtonGroup** and then the BlackBerry will take care of unchecking for you.

Comment: I wanted to do radio buttons, but the UI seemed better to look at when using check boxes and I didn't want to create custom radio buttons since this seemed a much simpler alternative :S